# cardCornerRadius shows error

Tags: android, xml

I am learning android material design but in between it keeps giving an error. Can anyone help me on this?

> workspace/RecyclerCardView/res/layout/list_item_row.xml:2: error: No resource identifier found for attribute 'cardCornerRadius' in package 'com.Zybo.recyclercardview'

```
<android.support.v7.widget.CardView  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:card_view="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:layout_margin="5dp"
card_view:cardCornerRadius="5dp" >

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/img_id"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="7dp" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/txt_id"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Hellooo..." />
</LinearLayout>

</android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
```

Comment: make sure you are have added v7 support library

Comment: I have created a separate library with card view and recycler view classes and added that as a support library for this project. Also i have added the dependencies in build.gradle file.

Comment: Use app:cardCornerRadius instead of card_view:cardCornerRadius 
 as @RynohRR suggested.

Comment: Thanks for `xmlns:card_view="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Thanks all for trying to solve the question.
At last I got the answer for my question:

1. Import the card view and recycle view separately from `sdk/extras/v7/cardview`
2. `sdk/extras/v7/recycleview`
3. right click on the imported projects go to properties and check the library box.
4. Now go the main project where you are working and add these two libraries by right clicking on the project go to properties-->android(left side)-->click add(library) (right bottom side) and the required libraries.

Comment: Thanks! I though it comes under support design. Yes, we need to add the dependencies of cardview and recycleview.

compile 'com.android.support:design:23.4.0'
compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:23.4.0'
compile 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:23.4.0'

Answer (score 36):

```
implementation 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:27.1.1'
implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:27.1.1'
implementation 'com.android.support:design:27.1.1'
```

Above is sufficient.

Comment: this worked. Added card view package support to the build.gradle file

Answer (score 17):

Add these dependencies to build.gradle. 
 Use the keyword `implementation` instead of `compile` as it has been deprecated

```
implementation 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:26.1.0' 
implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.1.0'
```

then use

```
app:cardCornerRadius="5dp"
```

instead of

```
card_view:cardCornerRadius="5dp"
```

Comment: I have xmlns:card_view="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto" in the <android.support.v7.widget.CardView declaration which allows you to leave card_view: and it's working.

Answer (score 9):

This worked for me

```
app:cardCornerRadius="5dp"
app:cardElevation="2dp"
```

Answer (score 4):

Add in `build.gradle` under dependencies in app.

```
implementation 'androidx.cardview:cardview:1.0.0'
implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.0.0'
```

Or

Try do Refactor --> Migrate to AndroidX.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question.
please [edit] your answer to ensure that it improves upon other answers already present in this question.

Comment: for android x this work for me  implementation 'androidx.cardview:cardview:1.0.0'
implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.0.0'

Answer (score 3):

use this

```
<android.support.v7.widget.CardView
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:cardCornerRadius="10dp"
        >
```

Comment: Iam sry to say that even the above  code is not working.

Answer (score 1):

Do the following,

As I am using this:-

**build.gradle[app]**:--

```
implementation 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:27.1.1'
implementation 'com.android.support:design:27.1.1'
```

Layout file:-

```
<android.support.v7.widget.CardView
        tools:style="@style/CardView"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_margin="10dp"
        cardCornerRadius="7dp"
        cardElevation="4dp"/>
```

Use cardCornerRadius="7dp" as directly as shown in above.